# Post Processing Hadoop Data and storing it in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hadoop, npm

I am using Timothy npm for doing map-reduce jobs in node.js. I am able to run the simple word-count problem example and produce the output. Can anyone please help me understand how to store the output generated by Hadoop in MongoDB for post processing.

`require('timothy')
    .configure({
        hadoopHome: "/usr/local/hadoop",
        config: './hadoop.xml',
        input: "/user/loremipsum.txt",
        output: "/user/processed_"+(new Date().getTime()),
        name: "Timothy Word Count Example",
        cmdenv: "var=",
        "mapred.map.tasks": 10
    })`

This is my configuration for connection with hadoop. The processed file is stored in hadoop HDFS: /user directory.